# Pandas to produce date_range in minutes

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to look for a solution for the parameter `freq` in the `pandas.date_range`. I have seen that the default value is `D` which is for the daily. So, I thought for minutes `M` could be used. But I got monthly output dataframes.

I have gone through the examples from the documenation, but I could not see anything related to minute-wise `date_range`. See the what following:

```
>>> pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', periods=5, freq='M')
DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-31', '2018-02-28', '2018-03-31', '2018-04-30',
               '2018-05-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```

So how I can get the minute values using the `Pandas.date_range()`?
Let me know

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `T` or `Min`, `M` is for end of months [offset](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases):

```
dates = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', periods=5, freq='T')
print (dates)
DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-01 00:00:00', '2018-01-01 00:01:00',
               '2018-01-01 00:02:00', '2018-01-01 00:03:00',
               '2018-01-01 00:04:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='T')
```

---

```
dates = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', periods=5, freq='Min')
print (dates)
DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-01 00:00:00', '2018-01-01 00:01:00',
               '2018-01-01 00:02:00', '2018-01-01 00:03:00',
               '2018-01-01 00:04:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='T')
```